# Need IMAP client that does not wait and wait and wait for confirmation that copy was put in Sent folder

Tags: imap, email-client

Our mail provider (Rackspace) does not send a confirmation that the message was saved to the IMAP Sent folder on the mail server. I need an IMAP client that can be told not to wait for such a confirmation.

Comment: Which one are you using right now (that's having the problem)?

Comment: In other words the client sends the command to save a message to a folder (which is an IMAP `APPEND` command) and the IMAP server simply doesn't reply at all to his command? That would be a protocol violation on the part of the server and it would not be surpising for many or most IMAP clients to have dificulty tolerating that. That Rackspace's IMAP server would be violating the protocol like this sounds fishy.

Comment: It's what Rackspace tech support told me when we were troubleshooting the problem